# How can we stop the data being send whenever there in invalid popover message in the form of bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

The problem in this form is whenever the empty field is entered it shows a popover "saying this field is required", but the message is posted into the database.

How can I stop this until all of the popover is made valid?

[image: screenshot]

```
<form class="form-asd" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
    <hr />
    EmailAddress:
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Address" required />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="btnLogin">
        Login
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: use jquery `preventDefault()` http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: That "popover" is shown by the browser since you're using the `required` attribute. It has nothing to do with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with Bootstrap. You can use Bootstrap to do the validation UX, but your question is about halting form submit until certain requirements are met.

```
$('#myForm')submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // do validation, present popovers, etc.

    if (validation is good) {
        $(this).submit();
    }
});
```